# Framework7 turn off back button event

Tags: html, events, button, back, html-framework-7

I have standard code:

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="left sliding"><a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
<div class="center sliding">About</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I turn off an event that occurs when a back button clicking?

Comment: when you say back button is it phone back button or the back link which is mentioned in the code?

Comment: the back link which is mentioned in the code

Comment: you wish disable it for home page or for every page. or just want to prevent default behavior to perform other operation. The best thing is just remove back that does the trick